# Перевод описания раздела "Лучшие сообщения" в профиле пользователя

Tags: дефект, локализация

- Переходим в профиль пользователя
- Выбираем вкладку "Профиль"(не активность)
- Спускаемся до раздела "Лучшие сообщения"

Там вы видим:

- *"View all questions, answers, and articles"* в описании раздела
- *"Articles"* в табах справа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо это связано с добавлением "Статей".
Раньше не припомню данного функционала
(Хотя я могу не помнить из-за того что репы не хватало)

Тем не менее было бы здорово его перевести.
@αλεχολυτ, Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Это нет смысла переводить, т.к. оно [должно остаться](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371837/339911) только на enSO.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, XD XD XD ... да уж, молодцы. о...фигенно смержились)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это баг
Данный функционал никогда не предназначался для ruSO
*(как и предназначался для enSO)*

Вопрос зарегистрирован на MSE
[Articles on MSE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371837/articles-on-mse)

Данное изменение откатили.
Переводы данных разделов и элементов не требуются.

**Вопрос больше неактуален.**